# UITableView - centering of Sections

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using a table view with its style set as "Grouped". I have only 2 sections to be displayed in the table view and the table view does not occupy full iPhone screen (It has some other views with it). So I would like to display those 2 sections centered in the table view rather than displaying the sections from the top of table view.

One round about way is to set header and footer of the table view appropriately. But the disadvantage of this is, each sections will be equidistant (looks awkward!). Anybody with solutions to it?

Thanks,
Raj